# How to solve an error with pivot tables in python

Tags: python, dataframe, pivot

I have a similar file like this one:

```
    movieId     title   genres  userId  rating  timestamp

0   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy     1   4.0     964982703
1   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy     5   4.0     847434962
2   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy     7   4.5     1106635946
3   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy     15  2.5     1510577970
4   1   Toy Story (1995)    Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy     17  4.5     1305696483
5   6   Heat (1995)     Action|Crime|Thriller   373     5.0     846830247
6   6   Heat (1995)     Action|Crime|Thriller   380     5.0     1494278663
7   6   Heat (1995)     Action|Crime|Thriller   385     3.0     840648313
8   6   Heat (1995)     Action|Crime|Thriller   386     3.0     842613783
9   6   Heat (1995)     Action|Crime|Thriller   389     5.0     857934242
```

I ran this code to obtain the full data and to process it:

```
! wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/z4zoofdgdrxe01r/movies.csv
! wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/f328xczt6vju6hi/ratings.csv
import pandas as pd
df_movies = pd.read_csv('movies.csv')
df_ratings = pd.read_csv('ratings.csv')
df_merged=pd.merge(df_movies, df_ratings, how='inner')
```

this is the code with I have issues:

```
df_merged.pivot(index='movieId', columns='title', values='rating')
```

I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-74-ad6b3a589ea8> in <module>()
----> 1 df_merged.pivot(index='movieId', columns='title', values='rating')

5 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/reshape/reshape.py in _make_selectors(self)
    177 
    178         if mask.sum() < len(self.index):
--> 179             raise ValueError("Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape")
    180 
    181         self.group_index = comp_index

ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

**What I want is to know which movie has more votes by doing a resume table like a `Dynamic Table` in excel**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward method to get the counts of groups is to use the `DataFrame.value_counts()` method that was introduced with pandas 1.1. For earlier versions of pandas a similar result can be achieved by using the `Series.value_counts()` method. Other alternatives include `DataFrame.gropuby()` and `DataFrame.pivot_table()`. These might be preferred if you want to aggregate the data using multiple criteria beyond just counting the number of items.

**Setup**

```
import pandas as pd

df_merged = pd.DataFrame({'movie id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], 
                  'title': ['Toy Story (1995)', 'Toy Story (1995)', 'Toy Story (1995)','Toy Story (1995)', 'Toy Story (1995)', 'Heat (1995)', 'Heat (1995)', 'Heat (1995)', 'Heat (1995)', 'Heat (1995)'], 
                  'rating': [4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 2.5, 4.5, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0]})
```

**value_counts()**

To get the number of votes, use `.value_counts()` to count the number of items:

```
df_merged.value_counts('title')
```

This will return a new series that has the titles of the movies as the index and the number of ratings on each movie as the values.

```
Heat (1995)         5
Toy Story (1995)    5
Name: title, dtype: int64
```

For versions of pandas before 1.1, you can use `.value_counts()` on a Series to get a similar result:

```
df_merged['title'].value_counts()
```

**groupby**

Another approach is to use `.gropuby()` with `.size()`:

```
df_merged.groupby('title').size()
```

**pivot_table()**

This can also be done using the `.pivot_table()` method:

```
df_merged.pivot_table(values='rating', index=['title'], aggfunc='count')
```

Which produces a DataFrame as output:

```
               rating
title   
Heat (1995)         5
Toy Story (1995)    5
```

The `pivot_table` approach could be useful if you wanted to aggregate using multiple critera, for example, the number of ratings and the average (mean) rating:

```
df_merged.pivot_table(values='rating', index=['title'], aggfunc=('count','mean'))

                  count  mean
title                        
Heat (1995)           5   4.2
Toy Story (1995)      5   3.9
```

Comment: I got `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'value_counts'`

Comment: This works for pandas >= 1.1. Are you using an older version of pandas?

Comment: I am using it with google colabs, then, the answer is i do not know

Comment: I just opened a new notebook in colab and ran: `import pandas; pandas.__version__` and got 1.0.5. I'll update my answer to work for this version.

Comment: you shared three options, first no work (version issue), second yes, and third no work, i got `KeyError: 'titles'`

Comment: The third was just a typo on my part. I had 'titles' but your column is 'title'. It's fixed now.

Comment: +1, yes, it worked. thank you so much for your time and effort, but, i am learning python, a begginer, and would it be too much to ask that you can complete or post another answer with `df_merged.pivot`? My need and my argument are that i want to handle big databases like in excel with `dynamic tables`, that is my need, i understand if you do not have time

Comment: The `DataFrame.pivot()` command just re-shapes a DataFrame, it doesn't aggregate any of the data. I've updated my answer to show how this can be done using `DataFrame.pivot_table()`, which is similar to Pivot Tables in Excel and may be what you were trying to do with `pivot`. If this isn't the output that you want, please update your question with a clear example of what you expect the output to look like.